# Relationships: how to get 'one to one' data after many to many consult

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

as the title says I'm trying to access to a row that it's related to a one to one relationship, I've tried with the method that is in my model but it only works when the result isnt a collection, it maybe needs a more complicated consult, do you have any ideas how to do it with eloquent

**Empresa model**

```
public function transferencias_recibidas()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Transferencia_recibir', 'empresa_transferencia_recibir', 'empresa_id', 'transferencia_recibir_id');
    }
```

**Transferencia_recibir model (the inverse of a hasOne relation)**

```
 public function transferencia()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Transferencia');
    }
```

**This is what i get, a collection**
[image: This is what i get a collection]

**This is what a need for each one of them**

```
$a=$empresa->transferencias_recibidas->find(1)->transferencia
```

[image: This is what a need for each one of them]

Thx for the help guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eloquent relationship are "lazy loaded", meaning they will only load their relationship data when you actually access them. The output you shown are expected because you did not accessed that relationship, but you can load that relationship in two ways:

1. access it when needed:

   ```
   $empresa->transferencias_recibidas->first()->transferencia;
   ```
2. "Eager load" all the `transferencia` relationship

   ```
   Empresa::with('transferencias_recibidas.transferencia')->where([ .. ])->get();
   ```

The second method alleviates the N + 1 query problem. Since the first method executes N queries to retrieve all relationship, instead of a query to retrieve all the relationship for the second method.

You may need to check [eager loading section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Comment: Thank you so much, it work!!, is there any way to get the data without using the "where"? I was reading the eager loading, and i found that i can use the "Lazy Eager Loading" bcoz I already have my parent model **$empresa**, but if i use this one, i only get all data that is in my table "empresas", this Empresa::all(), which i dont need haha

Comment: how you got `$empresa`? If you are using `Empresa::find($id)`, then you can change to `Empresa::where('id', $id)->with('transferencias_recibidas.transferencia')->first()`

Comment: Yeah with the find method, It's literally the same, dont u think?.
In the first case I had to use the where here `$empresa->with('transferencias_recibidas.transferencia')->where('id',$id)->get();`
and now with your code, and yes it works in both cases but we have to create a new variable and not using the older one. I dont know if am i explaining hahaha anyway thak you